# ContractResolver, lowercase with underscore (snake case property names)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

//this is camel casing

```
    services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        })
```

How set to lowercase with underscore?

```
{
  "just_like_this": "myvalue",
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would probably want to use the `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy` with a `DefaultContractResolver`

```
DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
};

services
    .AddMvcCore()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = contractResolver;
    });
```

Reference [Snake case property names](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySnakeCase.htm)